# How to assign Jade variable to Angular bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

Here is a little question, I have jade variable so i want to assign that jade variable to angular bind.

But it's return [Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=App&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.3%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:10:403%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:29:147%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:28:212)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:28:455%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:43:287%0A%20%20%20%20at%20h%20(http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:11:348)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:43:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ub%20(http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:47:164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fjs%2FAngular.min.js:24:463)

**Here is my Jade**

```
- var editor = false // my variable 
.content
    .title Title

     // that i want to assign 
    - editor = {{editormode}} // $scope.editormode = true || false return
    if editor
       .title-edit
```

Comment: Jade compiles to HTML and the HTML will use as template in angular. How should Jade know your scope? Do you render the templates on runtime? How is your setup? More infos please.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Angular scope variables in Jade control expressions. Jade compiles templates into resulting HTML used by Angular, not otherway around.

In your case you probably want `ngIf` directive:

```
- var editor = false // my variable 
.content
    .title Title 
    .title-edit(ng-if="editormode")
```

Answer (score 1):

Jade is a server-side engine which has the sole purpose of generating an HTML from a template, which Angular has no interaction with. Angular is a client-side framework which works with the HTML received from the server. A way to achieve what you want is to store your editor variable into an `<input type="hidden">` and then access its value via Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used jade and angular together before but if you are successfully passing your 'editormode' variable to the jade template then the following will work:

```
.content
  .title Title

  if editormode
     .title-edit
```